# OSGi maven-bundle-plugin leaving out my package

Tags: maven, osgi, jbossfuse, fuseesb, maven-bundle-plugin

I've got a CXF web service app in Fuse, and it's got a reference in a camel context xml file to a jar containing my files generated from a WSDL.

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="LookupEndpoint"
                 address="${my.LookupUri}"
                 serviceClass="com.whatever.IWebService"
                 wsdlURL="wsdl/MyWsdl.wsdl"/>
```

`com.whatever.*` is in my `<Import-Package>` list.  The jar is in my maven dependencies.  I can say `import com.whatever.IWebService;` and it doesn't complain.

But maven-bundle-plugin doesn't include this package in the MANIFEST.MF

It includes all my other packages that I requested.  But not this one.  So in Fuse, when I deploy it, I get ClassNotFoundException, referring to the context.xml class loading.

It is very frustrating.  Is there a way to maybe force the plugin to import a certain package?  Because their auto-magical dependency solver is ignoring my `<Import-Package>`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>

            <configuration>
                <manifestLocation>src/main/resources/META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>

                     <Import-Package> 
                     *, 
                     com.imports.this.one.fine*,
                     com.imports.this.one.just.fine*,
                     com.imports.does.not.import.this.one.*,
                    </Import-Package> 

                    <Export-Package>
                    com.something.export.*
                    </Export-Package>

                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `<Import-Package>` with a wildcard, then an OSGi Import-Package header is generated for all packages matching the wildcard **that the code in your bundle depends on**.

If the maven-bundle-plugin is not generating an import for the package you expect, it means that the code in your bundle doesn't actually reference that package.

Rather than importing this package, shouldn't it be included in the bundle?? Why do you want to import it?

Comment: Hi Neil, the idea was we store the WSDLs and their generated classes in bundle jars.  But they are merely like shared libraries. We then have services, which expose endpoints using the classes in the shared libs.  (It works.)  But only if the packages are in the MANIFEST.MF.  I will check now if randomly instantiating the service class in the code somewhere fixes this...

Comment: That was it.  ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();  Son of a ***** OSGi. Thanks man

Comment: Not sure I'm happy about you calling OSGi a "son of a *****"! First thing, the problem was not OSGi at all but one of the build tools, maven-bundle-plugin. Second, what it's doing is documented and very reasonable.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I think the OP was complaining about his issue, then praying to OSGi for its existence :-)